# how to seprate an array to 4 segment and print it by 4 thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiprogramming

I have an array that is some text files path. I want to copy those paths to another folder. by one thread for example execute in 6 seconds. Do you think that if I use for example 4 threads it can be optimized or not ?
and also how I can do that ?
I want to seperate that array to 4 segments and every thread copy its segment path. It's my code that first search *.txt files in special directory and then copy all of them to another folder.

```
string format = "*.txt";
string directory = lblDirectory.Text;
// it's path of first folder that i search text file in it
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
{
    Thread t;
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, format, 
                SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        streamWriter.Write(Path.GetFullPath(item) + "\r\n");
        File.Copy(Path.GetFullPath(item), Path.Combine(index, 
        Path.GetFileName(item)), true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop .

Comment: if the folders are all on one drive and it's no ssd, stop thinking about parallelization, afaik normal harddrives don't work parallel. Your threads would be waiting for each other, or waiting for the drive to finish the other jobs.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using *Parallel Linq* (PLinq) and let .Net split the work for you, something like this:

```
  Directory
   .EnumerateFiles(directory, format, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
   .AsParallel()
   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
   .ForAll(item => {
      //TODO: be sure that streamWriter.Write is thread safe!
      streamWriter.Write(Path.GetFullPath(item) + "\r\n");

      File.Copy(Path.GetFullPath(item), 
                Path.Combine(index, Path.GetFileName(item)), 
                true);
   });
```